# How to print the integer difference of two columns (Rails 3.2.13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm very, very new at Ruby on Rails. I don't know enough to even to search for the answer. I understand if you hate me but if you could please find it in your heart to throw me the teeniest, tiniest bone.

### Here is my database

`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130502193545) do`

`create_table "employees", :force => true do |t|`
`t.string   "first_name"`
`t.string   "last_name"`
`t.integer  "employee_id"`
`t.date     "hire_date"`
`t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false`
`t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false`
`t.integer  "sick_days"`
`t.integer  "vacation_days"`
`t.integer  "sick_days_used"`
`t.integer  "vacation_days_used"`
`end`

### `end`

I just want to figure out how to have "sick_days" and "sick_days_used" talk to each other, as well as "vacation_days" and "vacation_days_used". Just a simple X - Y equation so I can print on the page how many vacation and sick days are still available.

Thank you for your boundless patience for such a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add pure Ruby methods on your Employee model to calculate and returns the differences.

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  def remaining_sick_days
    sick_days - sick_days_used
  end

  def remaining_vacation_days
    vacation_days - vacation_days_used
  end
end
```

When an employee is loaded you can then get the remaining vacations days with `@employee.remaining_vacation_days`.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote you up, but thank you. This worked for me. For other newbies who read this, be aware that you don't need the '@' symbol if it's under an each block, in my case it was "<% @employees.each do |employee| %>". In that case, just write out <%= employee.remaining_vacation_days %> to print it.